Group by terms that matched partially with tidyverse or equivalent (collapse sequencing data into groups)
I am not sure whether tidyverse supports fuzzy search or grouping and I would like to collapse some sequencing data into groups. This is because the sequencer may generate some artificial Ns at the ends, while the entire middle stretch is still identical. I would like to find an efficient way to isolate these sequences and group them (and count them).
For example,
ATCGACACACACACACACACACAATC, NTCGACACACACACACACACACAATC, and NNCGACACACACACACACACACAATN will be grouped into the same group by sharing the CGACACACACACACACACACAAT. Importantly, CGACACACACACACACACACAAT is the entire and representative sequence, and it will be used for the group name.
Some other constraints are

The Ns should only be found at both ends (at either one end, or both ends). Hence, if the Ns are found in the middle of the reads, they should be categorized as separate groups.
I am only concerning standard DNA (or amino acid) codes. Hence, DNA will use ATCG and N represents the random base while amino acid will use ARNDBCEQZGHILKMFPSTWYV and X represents the random residue.

Below is a toy dataset and the expected result:
data<- data.frame(DNA = c("ATCGACACACACACACACACACAATC", "NTCGACACACACACACACACACAATC", "NNCGACACACACACACACACACAATN", "NNCGACACACACACACACACACAATN", "NNCGACACACACACACACACACAATN", "NNCGACACACACACACACACACAATN", "ATCGACACACACACACACACACAATC", "NTCGACACACACACACACACACAATC", "ATCGACACACACACACACACACAATC", "NTCGACACACACACACACACACAATC", "NTCGACACACACACACACACACAATC", "AGAGTCTCGATCG", "TCTCTGATGCTAAA", "TAGCTAGACTAGCATCGACTACGACT", "TAGCTAGACNNGCATCGACTACGACT", "TAGCTAGACNAGCATCGACTACGACT", "TAGCTAGACTAGCATCGACTACGACT", "TAGCTAGACTAGCATCGACTACGACT", "NAGCTAGACTAGCATCGACTACGACT", "NNCTAGCATCGACTACGACT", "NNCTAGCATCGACTACNACT", "GTCGACACACACACACACACACAATC"))


grouped_data <- data.frame(DNA_group = c("CGACACACACACACACACACAAT", # as mentioned in the description above
                                         "AGAGTCTCGATCG", # noted that the sequence might have differen length, ideally, the suggested code let me define minimum matched length between 2 sequence, but let say 10 now, while reality will be over 100
                                         "TCTCTGATGCTAAA", "GTCGACACACACACACACACACAATC",
                                         "CTAGCATCGACTACGACT", # same as the first example
                                         "TAGCTAGACNNGCATCGACTACGACT", # Ns were found at the middle
                                         "TAGCTAGACNAGCATCGACTACGACT", # Ns were found at the middle
                                         "CTAGCATCGACTACNACT"), # Ns were found at the middle and no matter Ns were also found at the ends, the displayed results should ideally (but optionally to this question's answer) have the Ns at the end trimmed
                           count = c(11, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1))

I tried to use grep or gsub to make a temporary column and count for that column. However, I am not sure if that can accommodate dynamic grep (as the group name will be different and I am not sure what would be the longest representative sequence for each group).
I prefer to do the job in R, but I will consider other open-source languages if they do the job efficiently. Thanks!

Are all preceding/trailing Ns to be ignored when searching for matches e.g. no matches will start and/or end with an N?

@LTyrone Yes, you are right. If the Ns are only found at the ends (either end or both ends), they will be ignored. And the final matched group will be the one without Ns. (I think it would be nice to have one parameter that can specify what will be the minimum length of the final match, i.e. if the sequence has excessive Ns, it will be filtered out. But I think this can be done in a separate filter line by filter and grepl easily at the beginning and before the grouping. I tried to ask the more general question.). I hope this helps.

Some more questions 1) how many rows in your actual data? 2) In your actual data, what are the min/max lengths of the strings? 3) There is a potential for one string to have matches in more than one group e.g. in this simplified example where string match length = 4, ABCDEFGH would match ABCD and EFGH. These groups are mutually exclusive. How would this scenario be handled? Or are the chances of this happening zero?

@LTyrone sorry for the late reply. 1) There will be over 10M rows 2) The length is quite homogeneous to be 301 long. 3) This is a good question but I am not sure whether that happens; in reality, I believe most likely the Ns at both ends will only span 1-3 bp; Given the 301 bp long string, I think it is very unlikely to have sequences match multiple groups; when possible, it would be nice to have the options to choose from excluding them or counting them for multiple times. This question seems beyond the capacity of tidyverse/ data science, therefore, I understand if there is no solution.

There will be a solution, but it would most likely require a  very high-spec computer. It's beyond my SME, but try looking into parallel processing, creating a list of all potential strings of 100 characters in length, and working from there. Using a datatable may add some efficiencies, but with a potential list of ~ 2 billion strings, you're going to find it challenging. You could cast you search net wider, someone may have already created something similar in a different programming language. Machine learning might also be an option.
